# Manipulate cell borders in a table using only in-line css

Tags: css, css-tables

I need to change the border properties of a table that I've built, but I'm operating behind a Content Management System that doesn't allow me to edit the stylesheets, only the page's HTML.

So I am able to manipulate some table properties using `<table style="....">`, but when I use the `border` attribute it only affects the outer border and not the border that exists between individual cells.

Obviously I can add HTML rules to the `<table>` tag i.e. `<table border="1px">` but these don't overwrite the external stylesheet which influencing the border so I need an in-line CSS solution.

Is the only way to change the inter-cell border really to manually add a border property to each `td` or have I missed something?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: can you give us some code you tried?

Comment: While it would't pass a validator, couldn't you slap a block of styling within the HTML body? All browsers support it.

Answer (score 2):

I am yet to find a truly in-line solution, but the `scoped` HTML5 attribute comes really close.

In particular, with this feature you don't have to invent a new ID / class for the table and hope it does not conflict with anything else.

Example:

```
<table>
    <style scoped>td {padding:1px;}</style>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately at the time of writing it is only supported by Firefox.

Edit 2019: the features it was then later abandoned before adoption: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped and is now marked as "Obsolete"

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to overwrite an external stylesheet? If your inline CSS isn't working, you might want to try using -

```
!important
```

So you could do something like this -

```
<table style="border: none!important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is the only way to change the inter-cell border really to manually add a border property to each td...?"

Yes.

Unless you can add a style tag:

```
<style>
table td {...}
</style>
```

Of course, there's always JavaScript. jQuery:

```
$('table td').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use html you can insert a stylesheet and target the `td` elements.
You should add a class to avoid messing other tables in the page

```
<table class="some-class">..
```

and

```
<style type="text/css">
  table.some-class td{
      border:1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it looks like my CMS wont allow the use of a <style> tag or javascript either. Frustrating. No worries, i'll keep fiddling around for a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
table { border: 1px solid red; }
td { border: 1px solid red; }
</style>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```